# My For loop counter is not increasing as expected

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

I'm trying to replace the `j`th value of the function's input string to `'0'` whenever the `i`th value of alphabet is contained in the function's input.

I am expecting this for-loop to increment `i` whenever the `alphabet[i]` equals input `x[j]` but it gets stuck at `i` when it does. What is going on here??

**P.S** This is an introductory programming course (CS50) and it uses different syntax then standard C.

```
void checkrepeat(string x)
{
    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int alphalen = strlen(alphabet);
    for (int i = 0; i < alphalen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(x); j++)
        {
            if (alphabet[i] == x[j])
            {
                x[j] = '0';
                printf("%i,", i);
                printf("%c,", alphabet[i]);
                printf("%s\n", x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of function with value x = 'AAA' gives me

```
0,A,0AA
0,A,00A
0,A,000
```

I am expecting it to give me

```
0,A,0AA
1,B,0AA
2,C,0AA
```

Comment: *"I am expecting this for-loop to increment the 'i' whenever the alphabet[i] equals input x[j]"* - Why? You never increment it in that condition

Comment: "I am expecting this for-loop to increment the 'i' whenever the alphabet[i] equals input x[j]". Your code doesn't do that. The `if (alphabet[i] == x[j])` block does not contain any increment to `i`. Suggest you use a debugger to step thru the code and watch the variable values as it runs.

Comment: @klutt doesn't for (int i; i <  alphalen; **i++**) **i++** make 'i' increment?

Comment: @kaylum Maybe I am having a wrong idea for the For-Loop. I thought whatever it is contained inside the for loop is done, the 'i' increase from the **i++**.

Comment: Yes, it does increment, but that's the outer loop. `j` will run from `0` to `strlen(x)` once for every increment of `i`

Comment: @klutt Ohhh now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: OP isn't clear with `for` loops and has gone straight to writing a function with nested loops without any plan made on paper.                                                                                    
I'd suggest OP to **a)** brush up his loops concepts and **b)** make on-paper pseudocode/algorithms beforehand and perhaps even going to the lengths of writing the basic C code in order on paper(and tracing its expected execution) before actually running your code -- this reduces errors, gives you clarity on how things work and avoids such fuzzy misconceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first post so pardon me if I am too verbose or not following any unsaid rules; I would be happy to include any suggestions as I contribute more.

I could be wrong but looks like `"Your expected output pattern"` and `"your interpretation of assignment"` are **contradictory**.

Let me explain why ?

#### 1 - Expected Output for `x='AAA'`

```
I am expecting it to give me
0,A,0AA
1,B,0AA
2,C,0AA
```

#### 2 - your interpretation of assignment

> replace the `'j'th` value of the function's input string to `'0'` **whenever** the `'i'th` value of alphabet is contained in the function's input.

Here you are interpreting **whenever** as `"update input string with '0' for **ALL** matches"`
i.e. replace all `A's` with `0's`.

If I follow interpretation [2] then output of **your function code "as is"** for `x='AAA'` would print like this

```
0,A,0AA
0,A,00A
0,A,000
i loop with j=1 will run but nothing is printed because there is no B in input string
i loop with j=2 will run but nothing is printed because there is no C in input string
and this will continue till Z  
and the loop will end
```

BTW - I hope you can see the waste of CPU processing power in your solution.

If your interpretation [2] is correct then your expectation of output [1] is erroneous and vice versa.

ASSUMING interpretation [2] is correct then you need to change your code as below however the output would be different from expected output [1].

```
void checkrepeat(char x[])
{
    char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int alphalen = strlen(alphabet);

    for (int i = 0; i < alphalen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(x); j++)
        {       
            if (alphabet[i] == x[j])
            {
                x[j] = '0';
            }
        }
        printf("%i,", i);
        printf("%c,", alphabet[i]);
        printf("%s\n", x);
    }
}
```

And output of your modified function for `x='AAA'` would print like this

```
0,A,000
1,B,000
2,C,000
...
25,Z,000
```

As an example when `x='ABCDZABCDZ'` then the expected output would look like

```
0,A,0BCDZ0BCDZ
1,B,00CDZ00CDZ
2,C,000DZ000DZ
3,D,0000Z0000Z
4,E,0000Z0000Z
...
25,Z,0000000000
```

Open this link to see Working code in C

```
https://onlinegdb.com/rJhda-gMP
```

#### 3 - your interpretation of assignment

> I am expecting this for-loop to increment the `'i'` **whenever** the `alphabet[i]` equals input `x[j]`

Here you are interpreting **whenever** as "as soon as first match is found update input string with `'0'` and increment `'i'`"

ASSUMING interpretation [3] is correct, following code changes are needed to print your expected output [1]

```
void checkrepeat(char x[])
{
    char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int alphalen = strlen(alphabet);

    for (int i = 0; i < alphalen; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(x); j++)
        {       
            if (alphabet[i] == x[j])
            {
                x[j] = '0';
                break;       
            }
        }
        printf("%i,", i);
        printf("%c,", alphabet[i]);
        printf("%s\n", x);
    }
}
```

If I follow interpretation [3] then it meets the expected output [1] and for `x='AAA'` your function would print like this which

```
0,A,0AA
1,B,0AA
2,C,0AA
...
25,Z,0AA
```

As an example when `x='ABCDZABCDZ'` then the expected output would look like

```
0,A,0BCDZABCDZ
1,B,00CDZABCDZ
2,C,000DZABCDZ
3,D,0000ZABCDZ
4,E,0000ZABCDZ
...
25,Z,00000ABCDZ
```

Open this link to see Working code in C

```
https://onlinegdb.com/rJhda-gMP
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `printf("%c,", alphabet[i]);`is an error. You probably didn't mean to use the `,` after `%c`. Remove it.

Second,Its easy to loose the logic in nested loops, especially as a beginner. Write it down on paper and run through it, If you haven't yet learn about debuggers.

Now,you probably do not want `i` to `++` when there is a match between `alphabet[i]`and `x[j]`, because `i` is your loop counter, and should not be messed with like that (You have likely confused a `for` loop with a `while` loop or are coming from something like Scratch).

I would suggest declaring a separate variable, say `int x` for this task.

As already mentioned in the comments, you haven't actually implemented this incrementation to take place(with a simple `x++;` in the if statement), and have wrongly assumed that somehow the `i++` in your for loop has done it for you .

Again, I'll suggest you to hit the books and go back to see the exact workings of a for loop , which is **very** frequently used in C , so you **cannot** afford to be fuzzy on its key concepts.

Also, you seem to expect the string `x` to remain `0AA` ... If this is the case , why would the *first* statement in you `if()` be `x[j] = '0';` ? This will make **every** `j`th element of `x` that matches with `alphabets` a `'0'`.

Further, in the *expected output*, you have expected `alphabet[i]` to be `A` , then `B` , then `C`, despite clearly stating in your question that you had passed `x` as `"AAA"` (which obviously cannot then match with `B` or `C`).

Maybe you haven't written the '*I expect*' with clear forethough. Please do not include sample expected output if it is **not possible** with the code you have supplied in the question. It confused me, and could confuse anyone. I assume you drastically shortened the code for S.O. but supplied the expected output of the original code you have somewehere on your computer.